# c# infinite Calculator that displays all digits

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a calculator where you have two text boxes for numeric inputs and the last one which displays the number. However, i want to make it such that it will go to at least 80 digits without scientific notation(decimals don't matter). Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I would implement this ?

Thank you.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Addition 
        **resultAdd = Convert.ToDouble(tb1.Text) ;**

        tb2.Enabled = true;
        calcFunc = "Add";


     }



    private void btnSubtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //subtract
        resultSubtract = Convert.ToDouble(tb1.Text) + 0;
        tb2.Enabled = true;
        calcFunc = "Subtract";
    }

    public void btnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        double totalResult;


        switch (calcFunc)
        {
            case "Add":
                   totalResult = Convert.ToDouble(tb2.Text) + resultAdd;
                   total = tbTotal.Text.ToCharArray();
                   string x = Convert.ToString(totalResult);
                   tbTotal.Text = x;

                //   tbTotal.Text = x;
                   tbTotal.Enabled = true;

                   **totvalue = BigInteger.Parse(x);**
```

Answer (score 12):

If by "decimals don't matter" you mean you're only dealing with integers, and assuming your using .NET 4 or higher, then you should use [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) which allows for arbitrarily large integers.

(You'll still need to do all the GUI work, but you can use `BigInteger` for all the calculations.)

Short but complete example to show that `BigInteger` is perfectly capable of handling large numbers:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = new string('1', 80);
        BigInteger number = BigInteger.Parse(text);
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Okay, now you've posted your code, it's obvious what's wrong - you're going via `double` for no reason in this code:

```
totalResult = Convert.ToDouble(tb2.Text) + resultAdd;
total = tbTotal.Text.ToCharArray();
string x = Convert.ToString(totalResult);
tbTotal.Text = x;
totvalue = BigInteger.Parse(x);
```

You're not trying to handle `double` values - you're trying to handle *integers* so do everything with `BigInteger`. Change `resultAdd` to a `BigInteger` too, and then all you need is:

```
BigInteger result = BigInteger.Parse(tb2.Text) + resultAdd;
```

No need to do any other string conversions.

Comment: @FaRa13: Well what value were you trying to parse? We can't help you without more information. This really *is* the class you should be using.

Comment: It can be a arbitrary large number,at minimum 80 characters.     
string x= Convert.ToString(totalResult); --this is where i store the final textbox value.
BigInteger totvalue;
totvalue = BigInteger.Parse(x);

Comment: Then after a 20 or so numbers, it gives me an error saying cannot parse.

Comment: Well copy your 21 digit number here so we can see what may be going wrong, please include all of the parsing code too. ***Edit your original question to show these details***, not posting another answer in the comments, it is too hard to read code in comments.

Comment: @FaRa13: As Scott says, we need a sample of a value which fails. `BigInteger` can definitely handle numbers of more than 20 digits.

Comment: My apologies. Any number.111111..22222 anything and it gives me an error. I have edited my original post

Comment: @FaRa13: See my edit - the problem is that you're using `double` for no apparent reason. If you'd looked at the value that couldn't be parsed (which is what Scott and I were looking for) you'd have found that it wasn't a simple integer representation at that point, because you were using the string representation of a `double`.

Comment: Thank you all very,very much !